# Testcontainers image pull behaviour is too aggressive in private registries

Tags: java, testcontainers

I am using Testcontainers on a private registry and whenever it has problems with permissions or can't find an image it is retrying very aggressively and thereby the used useraccount always gets disabled.

In the [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-image-pull-behaviour) I only found the following:

> Customizing image pull behaviour
> pull.pause.timeout = 30 By default Testcontainers will abort the pull of an image if the pull appears stalled (no data transferred) for longer than this duration (in seconds).

Is there a way to prevent these aggressive retries whenever it doesn't find an image or can't authenticate?